# How to get a trace file for hard disk access?

Tags: windows, simulation, disk, hard-drive

I have implemented a simulation which takes trace file as input which basically tracks **each request** for read, write access to hard disk and process it.

Can someone tell me how/where I can get this trace (track) file or if is there any kinda option in windows to be enabled? If so, where should I look this file on hard disk?

Answer (score 1):

ETW and XPerf will do exactly this. Look into the tracerpt utility